# Import CSV values into variable VBA (MSAccess)

Tags: vba, csv, ms-access, import

I had an assignement at work to try and help setup something in Access, using VBA code. The problem is i'm very novice in VBA and can't find the code i'm looking for online. What i'm trying to do is quite simple. I have this CSV file:

```
DisplayName,"DisplayVersion","Publisher","Bits"
!Poste_HUB 3.9.1,"3.9.1","Plantronics","64"
```

I simply want, in MsAccess VBA code, to import these 4 values into separate variables so they can be used later on.

How does one go about importing CSV data with VBA? Please guide me in the right direction as I don't want to ask for complete code, just a bit stuck about how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command to link the file as a linked table:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , "TableName", "d:\path\import.csv", True
```

Then you can read the record and the four fields directly:

[image: Table]

Comment: Great, however is it possible to import the CSV data straight into an already existing empty table instead of creating a new linked one like that? My goal is to be able to DELETE the csv file after it's imported, so the data is persistent in that table.

Comment: Found it, using acImportDelim instead of acLinkDelim. Thanks, answer accepted